# Error in creating trigger

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I am trying to create trigger as follows when I got the error message "Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure defectTrigger, Line 15
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Set'."

The code is below. Can you please let me know what is causing the error.

```
use [DM]
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE  Trigger defectTrigger on dbo.tcefed 
FOR INSERT 
AS 
       declare @defID int;
       declare @clientID int;
       declare @defLog varchar(200);
       declare @datatime datetime;
       declare @status varchar(50);
       declare @project varchar(50);

select @clientID=i.ClientID from inserted i;    
select @defID=i.DefectID from inserted i;   
select @project=i.ProjectCode from inserted i,

Set @defID = 'insert into dbo.DefectLog values(@clientID,@project,@defID)'

 GO
```

Comment: @defID is an INT, how are you going to set that to a string? Also, your trigger code has a massive flaw: it assumes that triggers fire *per row*. What if you have an insert statement that adds multiple rows at once? This trigger will break (well, it will pick some arbitrary row from `inserted`, and ignore the rest).

Comment: I agree with Aaron's comment, but the cause of your error (to answer your initial question) is the comma at the end of the select statement preceding your final SET.  That should be a semi-colon.